# Close Android application after touching with three fingers

Tags: android, android-fragments, android-viewpager

I want to close my application when there are three fingers touching the screen (just like mac os). In my application I used both fragmentation and view pager, but I don't understand how to use event.getAction() and Action Mask.

I used Both

```
MotionEvent.ACTION_UP
MotionEvent.ACTION_POINTER_DOWN:
```

But they don't work.

When used a different ACTION_MASKED application is called multiple times.

```
int maxPointercount=0;
int previousPointercount=0;

public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
    int currentpointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
    System.out.println("My pointer....." + currentpointerCount);

    int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
    System.out.println("pre......."+previousPointercount);
    System.out.println("max......."+maxPointercount);

    if(maxPointercount < previousPointercount){
        maxPointercount = currentpointerCount;
    }

    previousPointercount = currentpointerCount;

    if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_) {
       if(maxPointercount>=3){
        maxPointercount = 0;
        Toast.makeText(MyclassActivity.this,"FingerToched!!"Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        Intent intent = newIntent(MyclassActivity.this,DashboardActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
        finish();
        //your code that will run 1 time
       }
       maxPointercount = 0;
       previousPointercount = 0;      
    }
    return super.onTouchEvent(event);
}
```

Comment: I would question why.  If you want OSX, then use a Mac.  I would be annoyed with am app that closed (and I assume you are doing something horrible like system.exit) just because it detected 3 fingers.

Comment: i dont understand what u want to say..bro please explain in proper language..

Comment: @ gaurav kumawat bhai mene ek question upload kiya h uska reply dhoond immediately

Comment: yehi question hai kya ....

Comment: @ gaurav kumawat ha bhai .....

Comment: bhai .code to shi..he khi na khi counters ki problem he.

Comment: if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_)........ye kya he bhai...

Comment: @ ho gya bhai m jis ne ans diya h uska poin up ke bhai niche ans hw us bandhe ka name h  Edward van Raak niche dekh...plz plz uske poin badha bhai.....

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This should work.

```
    @Override
    public boolean dispatchTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) {
        int currentpointerCount = event.getPointerCount();
        Log.d("hi", "My pointer....." + currentpointerCount);

        int action = event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK;
        System.out.println("pre......."+previousPointercount);
        System.out.println("max......."+maxPointercount);

        if(maxPointercount < previousPointercount){
            maxPointercount = currentpointerCount;
        }

        previousPointercount = currentpointerCount;

        if(action==MotionEvent.ACTION_UP) {            
           if(maxPointercount==3){        
            finish();
            //your code that will run 1 time
           }
           maxPointercount = 0;
           previousPointercount = 0;      
        }
        return true;
        /** This worked for OP's specific case 
        return super.dispatchTouchEvent(event);
        **/
    }
```

Comment: it is working but  when i used this code my inner activity has been  stoped. just like view pager  used after  my dashboard   but it cant work when i apply this code...inner layout doesnt work

Comment: What do you mean with your "inner activity"? Use getActivity().finish(); if you are working with fragments.

Comment: Hey dude, I have used ondispatched event on Activity. That activity contains view pager and tabpageindicator. So I have put used finish() that is ok but when I implement ondispatchevent to my activity. That pager and tab page indicator have been just stopped working that are included in current activity.

Comment: "Stopped working" as in they give an exception error? Or what do you mean?

Comment: I was asking you if there is any error. Your view pager doesn't recognize touch events anymore? Is that what you mean? Edit: Ah I see. Let me look at it.

Comment: Nope there is no any error any more bro!! If I just put ondispatchevent that pager's default swipe has just stopped. If I just removed ondispatchevent It is going to be work fine.

Comment: Hey brother done!! thanks a lot. I have ovverrided super.dispatchtouchevent(event) and solved my problem instead of return true

Comment: Cool! I'll change that in my answer then.